# Android MotionLayout crashes on RecyclerView scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have RecyclerView inside MotionLayout

Like this (it's example, there are other views inside fragment_search_menu layout):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_search_motion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_search_scene"
    tools:showPaths="true">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_search_map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_search_spacer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/fragment_search_spacer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/large_gap"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_search_menu" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_search_menu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_corners_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.63"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_search_menu_recycler"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

App crashes after recyclerview scrolling with this log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.onNestedPreScroll(MotionLayout.java:2200)
        at androidx.core.view.ViewParentCompat.onNestedPreScroll(ViewParentCompat.java:386)
        at androidx.core.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(NestedScrollingChildHelper.java:322)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchNestedPreScroll(RecyclerView.java:11595)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5286)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:710)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have this version of ConstraintLayout (latest): androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta7

And i have no idea what to do with this crash

Comment: as the crash says there should be something wrong in the adapter of your recycler view, it want to getId() from item, but the item is Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.

Please use androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6 instead

Comment: thanks, i reverted it to beta6 and rebuilt my project. It's ok now

Comment: Hi @RomanOstanin, if my answer solved your issue please accept it. Thanks